# Antdroid firmware upload error

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, arduino

I followed this tutorial today: [Uploading firmware to Arduino](https://github.com/antdroid-hexapod/antdroid/wiki/Installation#uploading-firmware-to-arduino)

I did everything as it says but when I try to upload the firmware to the Arduino it builds about 57% and then shows an error:

```
Invoking "antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload -j4 -l4" failed
```

Why do I get this error? Is it because I am missing something? I also noticed a line saying

```
...fatal error: string: no such file or directory...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
----------

[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/Antfirm.cpp.obj
In file included from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/firmware/controlRos.h:30:0,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/firmware/Antfirm.h:34,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/firmware/Antfirm.cpp:20:
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/include/antdroid_msgs/Walk.h:9:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/Antfirm.cpp.obj' failed
make[7]: *** [CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/Antfirm.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:279: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/all' failed
make[6]: *** [CMakeFiles/mega2560_firmware.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/upload.dir/rule' failed
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/upload.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:157: recipe for target 'upload' failed
make[4]: *** [upload] Error 2
antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload' failed
make[3]: *** [antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3922: recipe for target 'antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3929: recipe for target 'antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [antdroid/antdroid_antfirm/CMakeFiles/antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:1499: recipe for target 'antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload' failed
make: *** [antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload] Error 2
Invoking "make antdroid_antfirm_firmware_upload -j4 -l4" failed
```

Comment: Which file or directory is missing. You need to give us the details if you expect us to be able to help.